# Android dataStore with flow not get update after edit

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm use DataStore with flow but I cant get any update on the flow when editing DataStore.

Store.kt

```
private class IStore(private val context: Context): Store {
    val eventIDKey = stringPreferencesKey("EventID")

    override suspend fun setEventID(eventID: String) {
        context.dataStoreSettings.edit { settings ->
            settings[eventIDKey] = eventID
        }
    }

    override fun getEventID(): Flow<String> {
        return context.dataStoreSettings.data.map { settings -> settings[eventIDKey].orEmpty() }
    }
}
```

and manipulate `getEventID()` with data from room database in event service

EventService.kt

```
fun getSelectedEventLive() = store.getEventID()
    .onEach { Log.d("EventService", "income new event id $it") }
    .flatMapConcat { if(it.isNotBlank()) eventDao.get(it) else flowOf(null) }
```

onEach called when I collect the data but when updated it's not called again and need to close and open the app to show the latest data

MainViewModel.kt

```
val selectedEvent = eventService.getSelectedEventLive()
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, null)
```

and use on Compose with this

```
val currentEvent by mainViewModel.selectedEvent.collectAsState()
```

Maybe I doing wrong or maybe there is something I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i found the solusion its works if i change the `flatMapConcat` with `flatMapLatest` in `EventService.kt`

```
fun getSelectedEventLive() = store.getEventID()
    .filterNot { it.isBlank() }
    .flatMapLatest { eventDao.get(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you want to use `flow.collect {...}`, since `Flow` is *cold* and need to know that it is being collected to start producing new values.

```
// MainViewModel.kt
private val _selectedEvent = MutableStateFlow<TypeOfYourEvent>()
val selectedEvent: StateFlow<TypeOfYourEvent> = _selectedEvent

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        getSelectedEventLive().collect { it ->
            _selectedEvent.value = it    
        }
    }
}
```

This example should be fine with your composable's code, you still can collect `selectedEvent` as state.

Comment: It's not working. found the problem on flatMapConcat so i change to flatMapLatest